# How to select pandas dataframe rows with loc using the ligne index?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a big pandas dataframe from which I'm trying to select some rows with the `.loc` tool. The problem is that the condition I want to use in it needs an index which is given in one of the columns of the dataframe (the 'index' one). I try to select the row if the value is below a value that I need to found with the index in a simple list.

```
>>> df
r   v   index
1   2   2
2   4   3
3   20  1

>>> list
[3,6,32]
```

I want something like:

```
df.loc[ df['v'] < list[ df['index'] ] ]
```

So something which refers to the index in the studied row of the dataframe.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Can you create [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, convert the list to an array, and use "index" as the indexer:

```
v = np.array([3,6,32])
df[df['v'] < v[df['index'] - 1]]

   r  v  index
0  1  2      2
1  2  4      3
```

Where,

```
v[df['index'] - 1]
# array([ 6, 32,  3])
```

---

```
r = df.loc[df['v'] < v[df['index'] - 1]].copy()
```